# Make EntryElement look like a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using Monotouch.Dialog and I would like to customize an EntryElement to either make it look like a UISearchBar, or make it use, internally, a UISearchBar.
Any idea on how to do that?

Maybe I need to inherit from Element and create my custom element?

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe user the uiviewelement and add your own searchbar to it.